# Get info from the thread in pyqt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to get the queue from the thread and read it outside of the that thread and do a command. The GUI is generated using Qt designer. When i tried the code below it only print the None value for the self.que and it does not update. Below is the code that i am trying. Thank you for helping.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
import time
import cv2

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    changePixmap = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QPixmap)
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.que = ''
    def run (self):
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture('sample_video.mp4')
        while True:
            check, frame = capture.read()
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(120,80),(520,390),(255,0,0),5)
            convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QImage(frame.data, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(convertToQtFormat)
            video = convertToQtFormat.scaled(290, 220, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.changePixmap.emit(video)
            face = detector.detect_faces(frame)
            if a_face in face:
                self.que = 'True'

class MainGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.setupUi(self)
            th = Thread(self)
            th.changePixmap.connect(self.label.setPixmap)
            self.label.show()
            th.start()

                if th.que == "True":
                    print('Yey')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    detector = MTCNN()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainGUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send information from one thread to another you should use signals, in your case create a signal that sends a `str` and connect it to a slot:

```
class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    changePixmap = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QPixmap)
    changedQue = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run (self):
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture('sample_video.mp4')
        while True:
            check, frame = capture.read()
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(120,80),(520,390),(255,0,0),5)
            convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QImage(frame.data, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(convertToQtFormat)
            video = convertToQtFormat.scaled(290, 220, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.changePixmap.emit(video)
            face = detector.detect_faces(frame)
            if a_face in face:
                self.changedQue.emit('True')

class MainGUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        th = Thread(self)
        th.changePixmap.connect(self.label.setPixmap)
        th.changedQue.connect(self.on_changedQue, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.label.show()
        th.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str):
    def on_changedQue(self, que):
        if que == "True":
            print('Yey')
```

Comment: Thank you again for helping. I will try it. I will also study pyqt signals and slots.